# Open different view on initial run

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I'm trying to make my app launch a different view on the first time it is loaded up. I've got this code at the moment which implements that something should happen when the app is first launched. I've got this code but it lacks the code to open `Initialviewviewcontroller`. I have no idea how to do this so help would be much appreciated

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];

 if (!hasRunBefore) {
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
[defaults synchronize];
// what goes here??

else
{
NSLog (@"Not the first time this controller has been loaded");
```

So I should launch a different view controller in the `if` statement. But what should I put ?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution No. 1**

I've written a simple snippet for this thing because I use it quite a lot. You can find it [here](https://github.com/cojoj/BHFirstRunChecker).
Feel free to use it, fork it or modify it!

---

**Solution No. 2**

You can do something like this in your `AppDelelegate.m`

Add this simple method at the bottom:

```
- (BOOL)hasEverBeenLaunched
{
    // A boolean which determines if app has eer been launched
    BOOL hasBeenLaunched;

    // Testig if application has launched before and if it has to show the home-login screen to login
    // to social networks (facebook, Twitter)
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasAlreadyLaunched"]) {
        // Setting variable to YES because app has been launched before
        hasBeenLaunched = YES;
        // NSLog(@"App has been already launched");
    } else {
        // Setting variable to NO because app hasn't been launched before
        hasBeenLaunched = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasAlreadyLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // NSLog(@"This is the first run ever...");
    }

    return hasBeenLaunched;
}
```

After implementation of this method you can use it like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Determining Storyboard identifier for first view
    NSString *storyboardID = [self hasEverBeenLaunched]? @"MainView" : @"LoginView";
    // Setting proper view as a rootViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Looks to work fine except it doesnt like haseverbeenlaunched. What should I put in appdelegate.h

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed that I've changed something on github :) Will post proper example in just a sec!

Comment: @ThomasFarmer, iI've edited answer and now everything should be clear. Feel free to ask!

Comment: Do I use the storyboard identifier, or where do I find viewcontroller identifier

Comment: @ThomasFarmer you use this one as identifier:
http://s13.postimg.org/dbbw9ie93/Zrzut_ekranu_2013_10_18_o_22_04_52.png

Comment: Cheers , its improved now.

Comment: ALthough when built and ran it says ailed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: Do  you have a faint idea of what this is ;)

Comment: Hmm .That solves it but now it present me with error -3 springboard.